# how to write state reducer with nested objects

Tags: javascript, redux

My mental model of my redux state tree looks something like this:

```
{
  selectedDepartment: 'Chemistry',
  purchasesByDepartment: {
    Chemistry: {
      purchaseOrders: {
        ...
      },
      invoices: {
        ...
      }
    },
    Biology: {
      purchaseOrders: {
        ...
      },
      invoices: {
        ...
      }
    },

    ...(another department, etc)
  }
}
```

Here's my reducer

```
const purchasesByDepartment = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_POS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [action.department]: {
          purchaseOrders: action.json
          // but this wipes out my invoices          
        }
      })
    case RECEIVE_INVOICES:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [action.department]: {          
          invoices: action.json
          // but this wipes out my purchaseOrders
        }
      })

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

You can see in each department, I have a purchaseOrders and an invoices key.
I'm trying my best to write my reducer such that it does not mutate my state but I'm not having luck because each action currently wipes out the other key.

I launch two actions: RECEIEVE_POS, RECEIVE_INVOICES.

When my action RECEIVE_POS is dispatched, I can create a new state with purchase orders, but this wipes out my invoices.

When my action RECEIVE_INVOICES is dispatched, I can create a new state with invoices, but this wipes out my purchase orders.

How do I write my reducer so that I could keep both my purchase orders and invoices if they already exist in my state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Object spread** combined with **computed property names** helped me solve this issue

```
case RECEIVE_POS:
  return {
    ...state,
    [action.department]: {
      ...state[action.department],
      purchaseOrders: action.json
    }
  }
case RECEIVE_INVOICES:
  return {
    ...state,
    [action.department]: {
      ...state[action.department],
      invoices: action.json
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first create new state for the department by applying the change, then merge that into the reducer state.

```
const purchasesByDepartment = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_POS:
      let nextPOS = Object.assign({}, state[action.department] || {}, {
        purchaseOrders: action.json
      });

      return Object.assign({}, state, nextPOS);
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Personally I like to make my entire store immutable by using `immutablejs` which makes operations like this (and a bunch of other things) trivial:

```
return state.setIn([action.department, 'purchaseOrders'], action.json]);
```

Comment: I like this answer.  Looks like I need to spend some time checking out ImmutableJS

Answer (score 1):

I use the spread operator (denoted as `...arrayName`) to achieve this. It's es6, I enable the functionality with babel.

`Spread` will spread out an array into its element at it's more human readable than `Object.assign`.

Using your context, for a simple scenario in my reducer I just go like:

```
return {
    ...state,
    selectedDepartment: 'Chemistry or whatever' 
}
```

This will return an array composed of state, plus selectedDepartment overridden with the given value.

For embedded objects you can put it like this:

```
return {
    ...state,
    purchasesByDepartment: {
        ...state.purchasesByDepartment,
        Chemistry: {
            ...state.purchasesByDepartment.Chemistry,
            invoices: {
                {your new invoices object comes here}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer gave me an idea for using Object spread combined with computed property names to solve this issue